# Can I get NSError messages from my users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nserror

My app isn't crashing for users, but they do get NSLog messages which I didn't disable telling them what the error was, in response to an NSError being generated. It's a long shot, but are NSError messages stored anywhere, and would there be a way of me getting them from the user?

Comment: Messages you log with NSLog are stored in the console log of the device. But I think you need physical access to the device to get to them. You can see the Console in the Organizer of Xcode.

Comment: @Matthias That's the perfect answer - why not "answer" it? ;)

Comment: Because I'm too lazy. For something that would qualify as an answer by my own standards I would have to explain a little bit more. And I would have to figure out if there is a way how a user can get to the log. Feel free to turn my comment into an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an option you can ask your users to install the `System Console`:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8

This will allow them to send you their console logs.